# Sending mail in local environment using Laravel 6 - getting an error:

Tags: php, laravel, email, local

I am attempting to send mail in Laravel locally, and am getting the following error:

Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.1 Authentication required"

Whenever I upload the files to my server, the mail works just fine. I am only getting this error in my local development environment.

My config/mail.php file has the following:

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'secure.emailsrvr.com'),
'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 465),
'from' => [
    'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'mypersonal@email.com'),
    'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Me, Myself and I'),
],
'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'ssl'),
'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME', 'mypersonal@email.com'),
'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD', '••••••')
```

And my .env file contains this:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=secure.emailsrvr.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=mypersonal@email.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=••••••
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

I am using Rackspace for my email server, and have double checked that the host & port are correct. My username & password have also been verified to be correct. And again - I am reassured about their correctness because when I try on the server, the email sends just fine.

Additionally, I have done the following:

- Ran php artisan config:cache after each adjustment
- Restarted the server via CTRL+C, then php artisan serve
- Attempted to use other mail servers such as mailgun, mailtrap.io and gmail. The service doesn't seem to matter, as I get the same error no matter what.
- Have tried using both tls and ssl for encryption.

Any ideas on what else I can do to solve this issue?

T.I.A.

Comment: `MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl`  do u have ssl in your local ? system

Answer (score 1):

Looks like, in spite of everything, it was still a persistent caching issue.

When the server was stopped, and the default port was changed from 8000 to 8001, everything seemed to work just fine.

Thanks to @anas omush for his above and beyond help.

Answer (score 0):

Run this command

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Then restart your local server also use mailtrap.io on local

when you run config:cache you are caching config not clear. [Laravel Doc](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/configuration#configuration-caching)

Comment: Great tip. I didn't realize that config:cache didn't clear the configuration. That said - I attempted this, and am still getting the same error.

Also - to your response, I changed out everything in my .env file to the following:

MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=cfc934687b12cd
MAIL_PASSWORD=••••••
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls

After I changed the .env file, I did config:clear, cache:clear, view:clear, route:clear, and restarted server. Alas - still getting the same error :-(

Comment: what is MAIL_MAILER? must be MAIL_DRIVER

Comment: Sorry. That was actually code provided directly by mailtrap. I was wondering the same thing. I decided to give it a try in the off chance it would work. But neither MAIL_MAILER nor MAIL_DRIVER produces a different result, unfortunately.

Comment: can i have access to your device using anydesk ?

Comment: `config:cache` calls `config:clear` then caches the config

Comment: install anydesk application then share your id

Comment: Anydesk ID: 335 580 187

Comment: @lagbox yes you are right. I see that in core but it's wired sometimes when using config:cache .env file still cached.

Answer (score 0):

From everything you have said i see you don't have any issues with your configuration, emailsrvr.com is just refusing the connection from an unregistered or an unverified domain name and this is your localhost, they do this in order to stop abuse of their services.